# mysql returns a different value

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve the first data from a table with the following data

[image]

if I sort with descending it will produce the following values

[image: after sort]

and then i run the sql command as follows `select id from top order by view desc limit 1`   and hope to get the very first id which is id with a value of 1 but the resulting value is id with a value of 4.
maybe there is a solution to get an id with a value of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify multiple sort columns and ascending or descending for each.   You want to sort by id ascending within view descending, so:

```
select id from top order by view desc, id asc limit 1
```

If you just order by view, you will get some arbitrary one of the ids.

Comment: It slightly surprises me that `top` isn't reserved.